# Click on one card view in recycler is enabling other card views automatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an application. When user clicks on edit button I want to check for the user and enable editing of if the same user is the owner of the comment.

I am able to check for the user. But my problem is when user clicks on edit button of one comment, many comments become editable instead of one. I am not getting how to come out of this issue. All suggestions are welcome.

below is my adapter code:

```
public class ToadlineCommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ToadlineCommentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener clickListener1;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    String newEnteredCommentText, neededCommentId, text;
    ArrayList<String> postCreatorId;
    ArrayList<String> postIdForComments;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    String userId;
    int clickedPosition;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> commentId;
    List<CommentDataStore> data = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    private String userCredentials = "toadwaysIfocus:toadwaysIfocus";
    private String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes(), 0));


    public ToadlineCommentAdapter(Context context, List<CommentDataStore> data, ArrayList<String> commentId, ArrayList<String> postCreatorId, String userId, ArrayList<String> postIdForComments ) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.commentId = commentId;
        mContext = context;
        this.postCreatorId = postCreatorId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.postIdForComments = postIdForComments;


    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_comment_layout, parent, false);
  MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
   return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CommentDataStore current = data.get(position);

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(current.commentProfileImageLink)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.human_image)
                .into(holder.commentImage);
        holder.commentUserName.setText(current.commentUserName);
        holder.commentDays.setText(current.commentDays);
        holder.commentDescription.setText(current.commentDescription);
        holder.commentAgreeCount.setText(current.commentAgreeCount);
        holder.commentDisAgreeCount.setText(current.commentDisAgreeCount);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void setClickListener1(SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener clickListener1) {
        this.clickListener1 = clickListener1;
    }


    // View Holder object for Recycler View
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

        TextView commentUserName, commentDays, commentAgreeCount, commentDisAgreeCount;
        EditText commentDescription;
        ImageView commentImage;
        ImageButton commentEdit, commentDelete;
        Button commentEditSubmit;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
commentImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUser);
commentUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
commentDays = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNoOfDays);
commentDescription = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCommentDescription);
commentAgreeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAgreeCount);
commentDisAgreeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDisAgreeCount);
commentEdit = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCommentEdit);
commentDelete = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCommentDelete);
commentEditSubmit = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentEditSubmit);

commentDescription.setEnabled(false);

commentEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
  int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();

  if (postIdForComments.get(clickedPosition).equals(userId)){

 commentDescription.setEnabled(true);
                        commentDescription.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHighlight));
 commentEditSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  neededCommentId = commentId.get(clickedPosition);

  }
else {
Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_not_editable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 return;
}
  }
    });

}

@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {

  if (clickListener != null) {
 clickListener.itemClicked(view, getPosition());
  }

}

@Override
  public void onRefresh() {
 onClick(itemView);

}

public interface ClickListener {

public void itemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

For example if I click edit button in 5th card row I want only 5th card row to be allowed to edit. currently edit buon for 10th or 14th row will get automatically selected. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The views are being recycled. In `onBindViewHolder()` you need to reset them to their initial state.

**EDIT**

RecyclerView recycles views. When one of it's children scrolls far enough off screen, the child is detached and placed in a pool of recycled/reycleable views. When the RecyclerView needs a new child to show, it can take a view from this pool (instead of instantiating from scratch) and simply bind new data to the view -- in other words, it won't call `onCreateViewHolder()`, but it will call `onBindViewHolder()`.

When you click the edit button, you change the state of some views in the ViewHolder. Then you scroll until it's recycled, but it keeps all this state that it had before. You need to return these views to their initial state inside of `onBindViewHolder()` to handle this.

Comment: can you please explain it

Comment: Can you help me in solving this, if you have any link can you please give. I understood this but I need to see what changes do i need to do in code.

Comment: @Keshav1234 Do the opposite changes to the ones you make when the edit button is clicked. I don't know how much more simpler I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SparseBooleanArray`.

Look at this code and try to do this.

```
SparseBooleanArray mArray;
```

now define its size.

```
mArray = new SparseBooleanArray(yourArray.size());
```

now perform `onClick`

```
commentEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
         if (postIdForComments.get(clickedPosition).equals(userId)){
            mArray.put(clickedPosition,true);
         }else {
             Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.comment_not_editable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
         }
      }
});
```

And finally in your `onBindViewHolder`.

```
if(mArray.get(position) == true){
      commentDescription.setEnabled(true);
      commentDescription.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHighlight));
      commentEditSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      neededCommentId = commentId.get(clickedPosition);
}else if(mArray.get(position) = true)){
}
```

I hope this will help you.

**Edit :** 
You should initialize your `SparseBooleanArray` in your Adapter rather then `ViewHolder`.

Comment: How will this fix my issue?

Comment: you see you are changing layout on click. although RecyclerView using same layout for each position. so it is obvious if you change for one position, it will change for all. so in this case you have to store particular position. SparseBooleanArray will help you in that. we are assigning true on particular position. values of other position will be false by default.

Comment: not working. Control is not getting passed to onBindViewholder

Comment: try to perform click event in onBindViewHolder also disable your edit text in there..